# Why were my flags disputed on this terrible question?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I'm slightly worried about being perceived as a whiner, but honestly, this is driving me crazy so I don't care if I get a million down votes, I just have to ask:

Why were my flags disputed on this terrible question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555634/codeigniter-no-migration-could-be-found-with-version-1) even though it has nothing but down votes and no edits?

I can't honestly see how this question could be answerable or salvaged unless the original poster returns to clarify - and that doesn't seem to be happening.

Am I being overly sensitive?  Is there some value in this question that is beyond my comprehension even after searching the web and reading the actual documentation?  Did a bunch of people robo-vote this as "Looks OK?"

Sure, I'd like to be vindicated for my flag-flinging prowess, but more seriously, I'd just like to see this question gone and know I'm doing the right thing and not creating extra work for people.  It bothered me so much that I re-flagged it (I believe both flags are applicable), but I am thinking a third flag would be  a mistake, so just looking for some feedback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nobody voted this as "Looks OK", thank goodness.

But it looks like the users who reviewed this were unable to make up their minds whether the question could be improved or if it was unsalvageable:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7638264
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7642920
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7644123

Well, guess what — you're right, it's unsalvageable. Closed.

Comment: Ah so the "dispute" in this case is not triggered by anybody actively reviewing a particular flag, just because a bunch of users separately reviewing the question did not all reach the same conclusion.  Interesting, and now it causes me to wonder how many questions slip through this "crack" (I am guessing it wound up in the help & improvement queue behind 10,000 other questions and would have sat there for a long, long time).

Comment: "Should be improved" strikes again.