# Disputed off-topic flag for question (How to setup MySQL multi threaded slave replication?)

Tags: support, disputed-flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716274/how-to-setup-mysql-multi-threaded-slave-replication) question as off-topic and it was disputed. I can't understand how this hasn't been flagged as off-topic as to me it looks like an implementation issue not a coding issue which I didn't think StackOverflow was about. Am I wrong here? I'm asking as I'm genuinely confused and would like to know for future reference.

Comment: [This is how.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14922138) A "Looks OK" review in Triage will automatically dispute the flags on the question. It doesn't necessarily mean you're wrong. It looks incredibly off-topic to me.

Comment: Thanks @Kendra as I said below, I didn't realise that would happen. it makes sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41716274/timeline) of the post you'll see it got  a controversial verdict in the triage review queue:

> 3 hours ago       completed       Looks OK × 3, Unsalvageable × 2, Requires
>   Editing × 1

When a post leave the triage queue, the outcome depends on the flag, details of outcomes is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300787/2607247) (Courtesy of [Kendra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra))

In brief you just had a bad luck with robot reviewers.

Even in the "first post" queue someone clicked "no action needed" *sigh*

I did vote to close as too broad as I find one of the multiple questions is "how mysql is coded under the hood to choose a db per thread".
Actually there's multiple questions in the post, so it's enough to close it as too broad anyway.

Comment: Thanks that clears it up. I didn't realise that the outcome of a triage would dispute my flag automatically. I actually thought it was disputed by an individual reviewing the flag.

Comment: @Kendra According to [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290033/3627607) when the consensus is not clear cut, minority positions get disputed.

Comment: @Jinx88909 The only ones who can single-handly dispute flags are mods, and that's only if the flag is for spam/abusive. Otherwise, a flag being disputed means something happened in one of the queues.

Comment: @Tensibai Hmm, I could have sworn that was changed at some point to be "Looks OK" only... Maybe not, I stand corrected.

Comment: @Kendra Am I wrong thinking only mods can **decline** flags, and that review queues outcome is helpfull or disputed only ? (didn't dig on how the queues work for a while)

Comment: I don't remember the _exact_ scenarios, but there are a couple scenarios where the review queues can decline flags. I think one of them is a unanimous "Leave Open" for a close flag, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: After digging a little, we were [both sort of correct.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300787/2607247) Only "Spam", "Rude/Abusive", and "Very Low Quality" flags are disputed on "Requires Editing" it looks like. (And there's one of the review decline scenarios, too!) (I don't think you need to edit again, up to you. Mainly leaving this here for future users.)

Comment: @Kendra nice find, including it in the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @Tensibai I've just reviewed my other disputed flags, I don't have many but I can see now how the logic holds up with the review process. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jinx disputed flags have no incidence, so not much to worry about.